# VHDL: Convert String to Std_Logic_Vector

Tags: string, entity, vhdl, sha

I'm writing a *sha-256* hash function in `VHDL` and it takes in a `String`.  I need to convert this string to a `std_logic_vector` of bits. So, I must somehow extract the *bits* from the *characters* of the `String`, but I'm not sure of the best way.  As far as I can tell there does not exist a built in function to do this in any of the libraries.

Is my only option to loop through each index of the string and use a `case` block to map the *characters* to their respective 8-bit ASCII counterparts?  Or is there some way to convert a *character* to *bits*?

Comment: What exactly is the encoding/radix: bin, hex, ...?

Comment: I'd like to get the conversion in either bin or hex...is that what you mean?

Comment: ...Why the downvote?  This is an entirely valid question and hasn't been asked/answered anywhere else.

Comment: Duplicate of [VHDL: Is there a convenient way to assign ascii values to std_logic_vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900938/vhdl-is-there-a-convenient-way-to-assign-ascii-values-to-std-logic-vector). The accepted answer is equivalent to Jonathan's albeit not as succinct, and was instead making the point you could find an answer by actually searching, contrary to your own assertion). Your question shows a lack of research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a string to bits with a function like this (untested):

```
function to_std_logic_vector(a : string) return std_logic_vector is
    variable ret : std_logic_vector(a'length*8-1 downto 0);
begin
    for i in a'range loop
        ret(i*8+7 downto i*8) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(character'pos(a(i)), 8));
    end loop;
    return ret;
end function to_std_logic_vector;
```

I don't think type `string` is synthesisable, so this function is only useful for simulation or static initialization.

Comment: Maybe `String` is not synthesisable, but `Array (1 to Packet_Size) of Char;` is!